# Convert XPS to PDF

Tags: software-recommendation, ms-office, pdf, preview, file-conversion

I have been given an [XPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) file which seems to be readily opened only on Windows based machines. I was under the impression that I could use [Acrobat Pro](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/supported-file-formats-acrobat-reader.html#main_Direct_file_conversion_formats__Acrobat__) to convert the file to PDF, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there:

1. A way to use Acrobat Pro to do this conversion?
2. A recommended FOSS mechanism?
3. A good recommendation for an XPS viewer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a gmail account it will open and display XPS documents. Also there is an [XPS-Reader application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xps-reader/id733144613?mt=12) on the Mac app store.

Answer (score 6):

If you use **Homebrew** and like the command line then try this:

1. open terminal (cmd+space and write *terminal*)
2. `brew install libgxps`
3. `xpstopdf file.xps file.pdf`
4. `open file.pdf`

You will see the converted PDF in the *preview.app* ... i hope so :)

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for months!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With MacPorts:

```
sudo port install mupdf
mutool convert -o output_file.pdf input_file.xps
```

Answer (score 0):

GraphicConverter will open XPS files

Xee will open the preview image embedded in them but not the image itself, at least the ones I just tested.