# How to open Microsoft XPS document on OS X?

Tags: macos, file, file-conversion

I got an XPS file from my teacher and I couldn't open it using my Mac. It should be a lecture presentation. Does anybody know how to open it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just ask your teacher?

Comment: @patrix thank you for your comment, he told me that this an xps  file, but i don't know how to open such file.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213300/convert-xps-to-pdf

Comment: Or https://duckduckgo.com/?q=open+XPS+on+mac&t=osx

Comment: @patrix thank you again for your reply. but i can't even know which file is xps, as you could see this a zip and i didn't found any xps extension. i am not sure How this file is compound.

Comment: I've never worked with XPS files but I would assume that the whole ZIP file is the XPS file. Let's see whether somebody has a answer.

Answer (score 3):

Upload the file to your Google Drive, then view the file in your browser. 
You can also save it as a PDF from there.

Or download third-party software as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I did not find a "Save as PDF" Option. However you can print the document, which under OSX allows to print as PDF …